# F5 VIP required to have on External VLAN?

Tags: vlan, load-balancer, f5

I have following network diagram

```
              [Core Switch] <-- VLAN 20 external
                   |
                   |    <--- VIP 
                  [F5]
                   |    <--- VLAN 10 (Pool membber)
                   |
             --------------
             |     |      |
```

As per above diagram VLAN 20 is external public VLAN and VLAN 10 is Internal VLAN for WWW servers.

As per above diagram do i need to configure `VLAN 20` on my F5 and create `SelfIP`?

I think i only need to add VLAN 10 on F5 right?

## EDIT:

Core switch Interface config

```
interface Port-channel1
 description Connected_to_F5
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20
 switchport mode trunk
```

Comment: It all depends on if you have configured VLAN 20 tagged or untagged on the core switch. It would help if you could share the port configuration of the core switch and the IP/VLAN configuration of the F5.

Comment: @TeunVink, I have updated question with S/W port config

Comment: And how are those nodes connected to the F5, via the core switch or directly?

Comment: Irrelevant for the answer, to your question but I suggest you remove the `switchport access vlan 2` line from that port config.

Comment: @TeunVink Yes everything plugged into Core Switch..

Comment: @TeunVink, How about if i direct connect F5 interface to Coreswitch access port `VLAN 20` in that case i don't need to configure VLAN on F5 right?

Comment: I think you still need to configure a VLAN and add it as an untagged VLAN on the F5 port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SelfIP is for sure needed on External as that's where it will arp out for the VIP address. The one on VLAN 10 should be used so it can locally contact the box, otherwise it will refer to the route table on how to reach the node in the pool.

So you have generally three options from there:

1. If you're not going to create a local IP to the servers, you will HAVE to use SNAT, otherwise the servers will try to directly respond to the reqeuster and the firewall will have no idea why that server is replying to a connection that was originally destined for the F5 and therefore drop it.
2. If you create the local IP address on VLAN 10 you will need to either configure SNAT so the source traffic is destined back to the F5 and other traffic that isn't web (i.e. SSH/RDP for mgmt) is sent back to the original default gateway. If do this you are going to want to configure a new HTTP profile with the 'forward X-headers' option enabled so you can tell what the original source was, otherwise all your web server logs will tell you is that the F5 float/selfip is accessing the server for every request.
3. The other option with local selfip is to set the default gateway of the servers to the F5 and create an L3 VFS server to pass other connections that aren't for a specific VIP to the server, this way the F5 will still NAT it back out to the VIP ip to forward to the firewall and also permit traffic destined directly to the servers, if you choose this make sure your network devices have their next hop set to the F5 for that network on a local IP address otherwise you will get problems from asymmetric routing (I.e. local pcs forward traffic to firewall to there, then the server response goes to the F5, F5 forwards the response to an interface other than the original it was forwarded out of and the traffic gets dropped)

TL;DR You have to have a self IP in the external VLAN in order to proxy-arp for the VIP. Easiest option is going to be create a self-ip in both vlans then enable SNAT for the server VLAN.

Comment: superb!! explanation

Comment: Even with a SNAT, you will be unable to create a SNAT for a subnet you don't have a Self-IP in.

Answer (score 1):

Without assuming anything, if you want a VIP in the External network (VLAN 20) and be able to access nodes in the Internal network (VLAN 10) via that VIP then you should add both VLANs with Self IPs in each network on the F5.